# undefined method `with_indifferent_access' for #<Array:

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I've tried it in a number of ways but it does not work. I have in this project, another controller with the same code working, the difference that another uses the has_many relationship, and the one with problem is has_one and belongs_to. Let's go to the code.

```
class Endereco < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_one :user
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :endereco
 accepts_nested_attributes_for :endereco
```

The strong parameter in controller:

```
class Backoffice::UsersController < BackofficeController

def create
 @user = User.new(params_user)
 respond_to do |format|  
  if @user.save!
    format.json { render json: @user, include: :endereco}
  else
    format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
 end
end



 def params_user
   params.require(:user).permit(:nome, 
        :email, 
        :password, 
        :password_confirmation, 
        :cpf, 
        :tel_fixo, 
        :tel_cel,
        endereco_attributes: [
          :rua,
          :bairro,
          :cidade,
          :uf,
          :cep,
          :referencia,
          :numero,
          :complemento          
          ])
  end
```

When I send this json via POSTMAN I get the error> undefined method `with_indifferent_access' for #Array: on this line

> @user = User.new(params_user)

```
{   "user":{
    "nome" : "teste1", 
    "email" : "teste@tt.com", 
    "password": "123", 
    "password_confirmation": "123", 
    "cpf": "123321", 
    "tel_fixo": "123321", 
    "tel_cel": "asdsd",
    "endereco_attributes": [
        {
          "rua": "tt",
          "bairro": "tete",
          "cidade": "asdas",
          "uf":"asdasd",
          "cep": "12321",
          "referencia": "asdasd",
          "numero":"123",
          "complemento":"123" }
    ]
}}
```

Someone to give me a light? Thank you!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You made `endereco_attributes` in your input an Array, rather than an object (which then becomes a Hash in Ruby). Since it is a singular (`belongs_to`) association, Rails expects it to be a Hash, not an Array of Hashes. Array does not have the method `with_indifferent_access`, but Hash does.

Change your input to match the correct structure and all should be well.

Comment: User can only be registered via json, I still do not understand very well, I changed the endereco_attributes to only endereco and this time I had the return Endereco(#42380200) expected, got Array(#18448440)

Answer (score 12):

My json was wrong ... where I was with [] and should not

```
 "endereco_attributes": [{... }]
```

correct

```
  "endereco_attributes": {... }
```

Thanks.